# How to translate this algorithm from Ruby to Clojure?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, recursion, clojure

I've been solving a programming task in Ruby and after completing it I thought I should try applying my limited knowledge of Clojure to implement the same thing. I spent quite a bit of time but didn't manage to get it working.

The task is: We have array of coin types and expected sum. What is the best way to represent that sum with coin types that we have available spending minimum number of coins. So for representing 325 with coin types [100, 50, 20, 10, 5] we would produce the following result: [100, 100, 100, 20, 5].

Here is my Ruby code that seems to be working:

```
  def calc(coin_types, expected)
    calc_iter(coin_types.sort.reverse, expected, [])
  end

  def calc_iter(coin_types, expected, coins)
    sum = coins.sum

    return coins if sum == expected
    return nil if sum > expected

    coin_types.each do |type|
      result = calc_iter(coin_types, expected, coins + [type])
      return result if result
    end

    nil
  end

  # test
  calc([25, 10], 65) # should return [25, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```

And now two of my failed Clojure implementations:

1) (it takes forever to run so i had to kill it):

```
  (defn calc [types expected]
    (let [types (reverse (sort types))]
      (loop [coins []]
        (let [sum (count coins)]
          (if (= sum expected)
            coins
            (if (> sum expected)
              nil
              (first (filter #(not (nil? %))
                             (map #(recur (cons % coins))
                                  types)))))))))
```

2) (this one does finish in reasonable amount of times but returns wrong result):

```
  (defn calc-iter [types expected coins]
    (let [sum (count coins)]
      (if (= sum expected)
        coins
        (if (> sum expected)
          nil
          (first (filter #(not (nil? %))
                         (map #(calc-iter types
                                          expected
                                          (cons % coins))
                              types)))))))

  (defn calc [types expected]
    (calc-iter (reverse (sort types))
               expected
               []))
```

Comment: Consider writing your Ruby method `calc_iter` as follows: `def calc_iter(coin_types, expected, coins); case coins.sum <=> expected; when -1; coin_types.find { |type|
      calc_iter(coin_types, expected, coins + [type]) }; when 0; coins; else; nil; end; end`. Among other things this eliminates the variables `sum` and `result`.

Comment: wow! i love it, especially the trick with <=> -- i totally forgot about its existence :), thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

```
(def coin-values [100, 50, 20, 10, 5])

(defn coins-for-amount [amount]
  (loop [amount-remaining amount
         coins-avail      coin-values
         coins-used       []]
    (cond
      (zero? amount-remaining) coins-used ; success
      (empty? coins-avail) nil ; ran out of coin types w/o finding answer
      :else (let [coin-val              (first coins-avail)
                  num-coins             (quot amount-remaining coin-val)
                  curr-amount           (* coin-val num-coins)
                  amount-remaining-next (- amount-remaining curr-amount)
                  coins-avail-next      (rest coins-avail)
                  coins-used-next       (conj coins-used num-coins)]
              (recur amount-remaining-next coins-avail-next coins-used-next)))))


(coins-for-amount 325) => [3 0 1 0 1]
(coins-for-amount 326) => nil
(coins-for-amount 360) => [3 1 0 1]
```

Note that in the current form it doesn't accumulate trailing zeros.

---

### Update

In my original answer above, I never considered that tricky coin values like [25 10] might be chosen, so you would need 1 quarter and 4 dimes to reach a total of $0.65. The above algorithm would have chosen 2 quarters and then been stuck with $0.15 remaining and only dimes available.

If tricky coin values are allowed, you need to use an exhaustive search algorithm.  Here is one version in Clojure:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core demo.core tupelo.test))

(defn total-amount [coins-used]
  (let [amounts (mapv (fn [[coin-value num-coins]] (* coin-value num-coins))
                  coins-used)
        total   (reduce + amounts)]
    total))

(defn coins-for-amount-impl
  [coins-used coin-values amount-remaining]
  (when-not (empty? coin-values)
    (let [curr-coin-value       (first coin-values)
          coin-values-remaining (rest coin-values)
          max-coins             (quot amount-remaining curr-coin-value)]
      (vec (for [curr-num-coins (range (inc max-coins))]
             (let [coins-used-new       (conj coins-used {curr-coin-value curr-num-coins})
                   amount-remaining-new (- amount-remaining (* curr-coin-value curr-num-coins))]
               (if (zero? amount-remaining-new)
                 coins-used-new
                 (coins-for-amount-impl
                   coins-used-new coin-values-remaining amount-remaining-new))))))))

(defn coins-for-amount [coin-values amount]
  (remove nil?
    (flatten
      (coins-for-amount-impl {} coin-values amount))))
```

And some short unit tests:

```
(dotest
  (is= 48 (total-amount {25 1    ; quarter
                         10 2    ; dime
                         1  3})) ; penny


  (let [results (coins-for-amount [10 5 1], 17)]
    (is= results
      [{10 0, 5 0, 1 17}
       {10 0, 5 1, 1 12}
       {10 0, 5 2, 1 7}
       {10 0, 5 3, 1 2}
       {10 1, 5 0, 1 7}
       {10 1, 5 1, 1 2}]))

  (is= (coins-for-amount [25 10], 65)
    [{25 1, 10 4}] ))
```

So it finds all possible combinations that reach the correct total.  Counting the coins and finding the solution with the fewest coins (don't forget about ties!) is left as an exercise for the reader.   ;)

Comment: However, I am not sure it works correctly for the scenario when coin-values = [25 10] and amount = 65, because it returns nil instead of [1 4].

Comment: The greedy algorithm employed here is not correct for all possible denominations of coins. To be guaranteed an answer you need to include a denomination of 1. To ensure an optimal answer, additional requirements must be met.

Comment: @AlanThompson You obviously can, though. Just as said in the question, one quarter and four dimes will do it.

Answer (score 3):

This is a cool problem to solve with logic programming and Clojure's [core.logic](https://github.com/clojure/core.logic).

First define a recursive goal `productsumo` that takes a sequence of fresh logic variables, a set of denominations, and a sum that we want to reach. Those fresh logic variables in `vars` will equal the number of coins for each denomination when this goal succeeds.

- Bind *head* and *tail* vars for both `vars` and `dens`. On each recursion, we'll only be solving for the *head* var, and recursing on the *tail* until we run out of vars.
- Use arithmetic functions from the finite domain namespace to constrain new fresh vars `product` and `run-sum` such that multiplying each denomination by some number then adding that to a running sum eventually reaches our desired sum (or not)

```clj
(require '[clojure.core.logic.fd :as fd])

(defn productsumo [vars dens sum]
  (fresh [vhead vtail dhead dtail product run-sum]
    (conde
      [(emptyo vars) (== sum 0)]
      [(conso vhead vtail vars)
       (conso dhead dtail dens)
       (fd/* vhead dhead product)
       (fd/+ product run-sum sum)
       (productsumo vtail dtail run-sum)])))
```

Then to use that goal, inform it of the amount and denominations, and zip each per-denomination count into a map with the denominations:

```clj
(defn change [amount denoms]
  (let [dens (sort > denoms)
        vars (repeatedly (count dens) lvar)]
    (run* [q]
      (== q (zipmap dens vars))
      ;; prune problem space: must be 0 <= n <= amount
      (everyg #(fd/in % (fd/interval 0 amount)) vars)
      (productsumo vars dens amount))))
```

You can get all solutions by calling `change` with the amount and a collection of denominations:

```clj
(change 325 [100 50 20 10 5])
=>
({100 0, 50 0, 20 0, 10 0, 5 65}
 {100 1, 50 0, 20 0, 10 0, 5 45}
 {100 0, 50 1, 20 0, 10 0, 5 55}
 ...)
```

Each solution is a map from coin denominations to the number of those coins used to solve the problem.

To find the solution with the least amount of coins, you can `sort-by` the values/counts in each map. To return the list of coin values, you can `repeat` the keys by the values.

```clj
(->> (change 325 [100 50 20 10 5])
     (sort-by #(apply + (vals %)))
     (first)
     (mapcat #(repeat (val %) (key %))))
=> (100 100 100 20 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I like [Taylor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54469016/6013799) but as a direct translation from Ruby here is my version:

```clj
(defn calc-iter [coin-types expected coins]
  (let [sum (reduce + coins)]
    (cond
      (= expected sum) coins
      (< expected sum) nil
      :else (->> coin-types
                (keep #(calc-iter coin-types expected (cons % coins)))
                first))))

(defn calc [coin-types expected]
  (calc-iter (->> coin-types sort reverse) expected nil))

(calc [25 10] 65)
;; => (10 10 10 10 25)
```

Original author almost got it - only the sum of coins line needs to be fixed.